# Styles not applied when using QgsMapRenderer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Using pyqgis, i am trying to export some maps as images using QgsMapRenderer. Here is the layer/style setup, both load correctly:

```
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), 'Report', 'postgres')
styleload = lyr.loadNamedStyle(stylepath)
if not styleload[1]:
    print 'Error loading report selected style'

if not lyr.isValid():
    raise IOError, "Failed to open the reports layer"
else:
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

Here is how i export, using QgsMapRenderer...

```
renderer = QgsMapRenderer()
renderer.setDestinationCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(crs))
renderer.setLabelingEngine(QgsPalLabeling()) 
renderer.setLayerSet(QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().keys())

p = QPainter()        
extents = lyr.extent()
extents.scale(1.1)
renderer.setExtent(extents)

img = QImage(QSize(2050, 1150), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
img.fill(QColor(255, 255, 255).rgb())

p.begin(img)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

renderer.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())
renderer.render(p)

img.save(mappath, 'jpg')
p.end()
```

The problem is, i get the image out, but styles are not being applied at all, even though they load correctly.

Comment: It might be a matter of refreshing the canvas. Try adding `lyr.triggerRepaint()` after you have loaded your style and see if that does anything?

Comment: No... nothing changes.

Comment: Also added setCacheImage(None)

Comment: Can you specify the version of QGIS you were using?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nathan Woodrows blog, and some API doc reading i figured method using QgsMapRenderer is deprecated. (Seems that pyqgis cookbook is often way out of date) So, instead, i used QgsMapSettings and QgsMapRendererSequentialJob classes. I got settings from a canvas via canvas.mapSettings() method. Then the rendering procedure goes like this:

```
job = QgsMapRendererSequentialJob(settings)
job.start()
job.waitForFinished()
img = job.renderedImage()
img.save(path, 'jpg')
```

Works without a problem. **Keep in mind, that before retrieving settings from the canvas, you must set it up properly (layerset, crs, etc....)**

Comment: Awesome, glad you found the solution to your problem :)